Optimal Way to Filter Nested Dictionary by Property Value in C#
I would like to know if there another way to filter  dictionnary
public class location 
{
public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, location>>> Example{ get; set; }
}


public class location1
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Name{ get; set; }
}

i would like to filter  dictionary where Id  = 3 

I need to filter the Example dictionary where the Id property of LocationBO equals 3. Currently, I achieve this with the following code:
var filteredLocations = locations.Select(location =>
    {
        var filteredDict = location
            .Example
            .ToDictionary(
                outerKey => outerKey.Key,
                outerValue => outerValue.Value
                    .ToDictionary(
                        middleKey => middleKey.Key,
                        middleValue => middleValue.Value
                            .Where(innerEntry => innerEntry.Value.id== 3)
                            .ToDictionary(innerKey => innerKey.Key, innerValue => innerValue.Value)
                    )
            );
        location.Example= filteredDict;

        return new Location(location);

    })
    .ToList();

Is there a more efficient or readable way to filter this nested dictionary structure based on the Id property?

Your code will not compile with two classes named location

Having multiple nested collections, like Dictionary<... Dictionary< ... Dictionary<... >>> is usually a sign that you need to create intermediate classes.

@JonasHøgh Yes, I modified the code, it's in a different class now.

You can flatten the dictionaries down with SelectMany first, then use Where to filter based on ID:
public static List<location> GetLocationsWithId(Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, location>>> dict, int id) {
    return dict.Values                  // Start with a stream of Dict<int Dict<int, location>>s
        .SelectMany(a => a.Values       // Flatten to Dict<int,location>
            .SelectMany(b => b.Values)) // Flatten to location
        .Where(loc => loc.Id == id)     // Filter for locations with ID
        .ToList();                      // Return as list
}

(I don't think a double-nested dictionary is the best data structure for... anything really. Are you sure there's nothing better for whatever problem you're solving?)

But i want to return the Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, LocationBusinessUnit>>>
I agree with you, the code is nested, but I can't change legacy code; I might break behaviors

Your example code doesn't do that though? filteredLocations is a List<location>

All I need to do is filter the Example dictionary (Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Location>>>) and retrieve only the location objects where Id equals 3.

You could replace the nested dictionaries with a single dictionary with a 3-tuple of integers as the key type

Ideally, this is absolutely what should be done. This feels like a ridiculous XY problem.

I can't change legacy code; I might break behaviors ..

@adoulou If the current “Example” property is exposed to such a large body of code that you have no confidence that changing the type and fixing the resulting compiler errors will work, are you even sure that your suggestion above will not break some existing code that depends on e.g. holding a reference to part of the nested dictionary structure? Is it safe to replace the entire structure with a new one, or must it be modified in situ?
